# find hidden and non-hidden files via shell script

Tags: docker, sh, alpine-linux

I write a little shell script which creates a copy of several files with .dist extension without the extension during the up process of my container.

```
#! /bin/sh

path=$(pwd)
echo $path
shopt -s dotglob
for file in ./*.dist; do

    filename=$(basename -- "$file")
    #echo $filename
    name="$path/${filename%.*}"
    #echo $name

    if [ -a "$name" ]; then
        echo "$name already exists."
    else
        echo "copy $file to $name"
        cp -f "$file" "$name";
    fi
done;
shopt -u dotglob
```

Locally it runs nicely on my MacOs, but in the container Alpine uses not the bash but the sh as shell and it doesn't know the "shopt" command.

Is "shopt" something I can install or is it just a command available, when you use the bash?

How could I change my script, that the for loop finds hidden files (with the dot in front) as well as normal files if shopt is not available?

Examples, which should both be found:
phpstan.neon.dist
.php_cs.dist

Comment: Have you tried to compare `ls *.dist` vs `ls -a *.dist`? You could compare it with `diff`

Comment: How exactly? What would be the syntax of my for condition?

Comment: If you really want bash (rather than fix the script to run in Busybox) did you try `apk add bash`?

Comment: no I defintely would prefer a script, which works in sh . Adding the bash is only a last resort solution.

Comment: `for file in ./*.dist .*.dist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [POSIX shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) has specific rules for [Patterns Used for Filename Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03), noting:

> If a filename begins with a <period> ( `'.'` ) the <period> shall be explicitly matched by using a <period> as the first character of the pattern or immediately following a <slash> character. The leading <period> shall not be matched by [...] the <asterisk> or <question-mark> special characters.

The GNU Bash [The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) modifies this rule:

> **`dotglob`**: If set, Bash includes filenames beginning with a ‘.’ in the results of filename expansion. The filenames ‘`.`’ and ‘`..`’ must always be matched explicitly, even if `dotglob` is set.

So the Bash-specific `dotglob` `*` pattern is almost like POSIX `*` `.*`, except for a couple of specific corner cases: the POSIX `.*` will match the current and parent directories `.` and `..`, and if there isn't a non-hidden filename then you will get a literal `*` in the output.

Your rule of "files, possibly hidden that end in `.dist`" won't match the current directory at all.  You can protect against `*.dist` not matching, or against there being a real file literally named `*.dist`, by using `test -f` to only work on files that are known to exist.

```sh
for file in *.dist .*.dist; do
  if test -f "$file"; then
    ...
  fi
done
```